# Output of a command not passing to assigned variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was trying to test nginx config in a script:

```
reply="$(nginx -t)"
echo $reply
```

But $reply is not containing the returned text. If i put first line in a terminal, nginx texts are popping in the terminal, but if i put second line in terminal, nothing outputs.
My interest is to use that nginx test's output in a if statement

```
reply="$(nginx -t)"
    if [[ ${reply} == *"nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"* ]]
    then
            echo "It's there!";
    fi
```

Is there any way to get the output returned by the command nginx -t in the variable ?

Comment: What does `$reply` contain? Make sure to use `echo "$reply"` and not `echo $reply` to check

Comment: @thatotherguy nothing. echo "$reply" also comes back empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your conditional you're testing for an *error* message, which means that `nginx` most likely printed that to *stderr*, whereas `$(...)` only captures *stdout* output by default.

In order to capture *both* streams, use:

```
reply="$(nginx -t 2>&1)"
```

`2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout, so that stderr is also captured by `$(...)`, the [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).

Comment: A very straightforward answer that works perfectly. So are those stdout and stderr are some kind of streams ?

Comment: Yes, stdin, stdout, and stderr are standard streams in Unix-like operating systems - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams